# tool to fix another ubuntu from remote

Tags: live-usb, remote-desktop, remote

Notion of the LiveCD/LiveUSB is priceless.  I was wondering if such a parent functioning OS session can be leveraged to allow skilled people to fix a friend's broken ubuntu desktop from remote.  At some point we have all encountered during boot up the blank purple screen, or any number of other boot up issues which indicates box needs to get fixed.  If we had that broken OS machine at hand no problem to fix.  So I was wondering what it would take to whip up a liveUSB inspired boot up session which can get booted by a friend in a remote location to allow me to interactively fix their broken ubuntu install ?

The normal login to remote desktop software assumes the remote machine is functioning.  I need ability to remote login to fix a broken remote Ubuntu install possibly by leveraging a jacked up liveUSB like bootable OS to give me boots on the ground on that remote machine.

Do such tools exist ?   Possibly a baby step would be to cable together a working ubuntu machine with another machine which needs to get fixed and have one machine probe and interact, boot, do edits on the broken machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can have someone boot the broken machine from a live CD. Assuming there are no hardware issues it should boot fine. Then have the user either connect the broken machine to ethernet, or guide him/her through the process of connecting to Wifi. If the broken machine is behind a firewall, connect to the router (can even do this from the live CD OS) and install openssh:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

Then route port 22 to the broken machine (keeping it simple here). Create an account for the remote user to use for login.

The remote rescue machine logs into the broken machine live OS over ssh. The remote machine can mount the file system of the broken machine to check the logs and perhaps disable nonessential services and maybe configure it to boot into a console rather than auto-launching the desktop (so the remote user can boot, fix something, launch the desktop, repeat). Finally with the help of the remote user, remove the CD to try a reboot.

In a dire situation, you could install VirtualBox on the live OS and boot the broken OS that way (boot as a raw partition).

Comment: Consider adding an explicit step after network-up to install and configure openssh-server, which is not included in Desktop live images.